# I've downloaded Angular 7 project while my global version is 11 so ng serve , ng update all of them give me errors like that

Tags: node.js, angular, web-development-server

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try by using the below command :-

**npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server**

Or

**ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force**

Comment: no effect and this error come while trying to update to the nexy version which is 8 : :

Comment: The "@angular-devkit/schematics" package cannot be resolved from the workspace root directory. This may be due to an unsupported node modules structure.
Please remove both the "node_modules" directory and the package lock file; and then reinstall.
If this does not correct the problem, please temporarily install the "@angular-devkit/schematics" package within the workspace. It can be removed once the update is complete.

Comment: try this command  -  **ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force**

its working for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem downgrading npm to version 6

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.13
```

and then update Angular